# HTML Agility Pack Parsing

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I am very new to HTML Agility Pack. I am trying to find some documentation but having some issues.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="person">
<a href="blah1.html">Person 1</a>
</div>
<div class="person">
<a href="blah2.html">Person 2</a>
</div>
<div class="person">
<a href="blah3.html">Person 3</a>
</div>
<div class="person">
<a href="blah4.html">Person 4</a>
</div>
```

Using the parser, how can I only grab links within a div that has a class person?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know XPath? Do you know jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available on NuGet):

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
html.Load(path_to_html); // or html.LoadHtml(html_string)           
var links = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='person']/a")
                .Select(n => n.GetAttributeValue("href", null));
```

Returns:

```
"blah1.html"
"blah2.html"
"blah3.html"
"blah4.html"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following XPath corresponds to your description:

```
//div[@class='person']/a/@href
```

It will return the `href` attributes of the first `a` elements that reside directly under any `div` element with the `class` attribute that is equal to `person`.

If you are more comfortable with jQuery style selectors, take a look at using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) instead of the HTML Agility Pack.